# Bash: Finding and adding up numeric values in html

Tags: html, bash, sed

I have html-files with some of the following patterns:

`{value} Punkte(-n)`

{value} can be integer or float with one decimal, comma as seperator, max. 99,9.

So my task is to find all {value} in the file and create the sum of them.

I guess it is possible to do that with something like `sed`, but as I am very new in that I have problems to find the correct syntax/regEx.
Maybe there is even a more convenient solution for that (I have to add that there are multiple files and I need a loop through all of them one by one).

edit: Sorry, I was busy yesterday, so here is the concretion some asked for:

The patterns are in lines like
`<div class="box box-warning">Erreicht: 0 von 3 Punkte(n)</div>`
so the recurrence is actually the  `von {value} Punkte(n)`
and what I need is the sum of all {value} in the file.

What I got is only something like
`grep ??? | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' >> data.csv`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Sharing more details (like your attempts with `sed` or sample input data) can help others to see where your attempt is going wrong

Comment: Form a plan: 1) Isolate the value (grep) 2) Refine the value (sed) 3) Form a sum (paste) 4) Arithmetic (bc). Use a pipes to glue them together i.e grep ...|sed ...|paste ... |bc

Comment: The easiest is probably `awk` that has fields separation capabilities (in your case you are interested in field number 1, that is, `$1` in `awk` terms) and arithmetic capabilities. Summing all first fields is as simple as `awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' file`. The next step consists in reading the `awk` manual (`man awk`) and understand how to specify the locale such that your comma separator is correctly interpreted. Look at the `-N` option, if your `awk` supports it, and also the `LC_ALL` environment variable.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: We don't know whether this is field 1. The OP claimed that these strings are scattered anywhere in the document. They may well be in the middle of the line.

Comment: @JürgenO : Say that the string `<!-- 3,6 Punkte(-n) -->` occurs somewhere in your HTML document, should this 3.6 be included in the sum too?

Comment: @user1934428 Good point, we do not know. But I do not see where the OP "_claimed that these strings are scattered anywhere in the document_". @Jürgen O: These `{value} Punkte(-n)` strings, are they single lines or can they be part of longer lines. And if the latter, do you know something about the position of `{value}`? Or do you only know that it is before `Punkte(-n)` and delimited by spaces?

Comment: He says _files with some of the following **patterns**_, not _having lines looking like_. From this I conclude that the pattern can be anywhere inside a line, which also woudl be logical given that the input is an HTML file. From the post, I would also conclude that there is one space between the number and the `P`, but I don't know whether there can be more spaces, or maybe even a `&nbsp;`, which also would make sense here.  By and large, the question is pretty fuzzy, and the OP didn't even show his own attempt so solve it, and I voted to close it.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it is now a little more clear. {value} occurs all over the file in lines like the one I added to the question.

Comment: @JürgenO. _A little more clear_ only because you don't explain what is constant and what can change in your `<div class="box box-warning">Erreicht: 0 von 3 Punkte(n)</div>` pattern. We guess that the second number varies, else you would not need our help, but what about the rest? And can this pattern be split on multiple lines? If you want to design a solution you must first come up with a complete, unambiguous specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing HTML with `awk` and `sed` is far from perfect. Many things can go wrong. Using a real HTML parser would be much safer. You have been warned.

The following assumes GNU `awk` and `sed`:

```
sed -rn 's|.*\s(\S+)\s+Punkte\(n\).*|\1|p' | \
LC_ALL="de_DE" awk -N '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

It should work if the numbers you search for are always preceded by at least one space, followed by at least one space and then `Punkte(n)`, all on the same line, and you never have more than one such pattern per line.

The syntax of the `sed` substitute command (`s`) is `s|pattern|replacement|flags`. The `|` character could be any character, we use this one because it does not appear in your pattern. The substitute command we use filters your input file and prints only (thanks to option `-n`) the encountered numbers of interest, separated by newline characters.

In the `.*\s(\S+)\s+Punkte\(n\).*` pattern, `.*` matches 0 or more characters. `\s` matches one space. `\S+` matches one or more non-space characters. `\s+` matches one or more spaces. The literal parentheses in `Punkte(n)` must be escaped with backslashes because we use the extended regular expressions (option `-r`) and parentheses have a special meaning: the sub-string matching the parenthesized part `(\S+)` is recorded for use in the replacement part.

The replacement expression `\1` is just the first (and only) recorded matching sub-string.

The `p` flag prints only if there was a match. The result should be the list of the numbers you want to add, one per line.

The output of `sed` is piped into `awk` that adds all these numbers (`$1` stands for first field in a line) and prints the result at the end.

We set the locale with `LC_ALL="de_DE"` (I guess you are German, replace `de_DE` by the correct locale specification if I am wrong) such that the decimal point character is the comma. As it is GNU `awk` we also use the `-N` option because by default it uses the point as decimal point character, instead of the one specified by the current locale.

Note: of course, if the `sed` pattern is not specific enough, feel free to augment it. Example:

```
.*<div\s+class="box box-warning">Erreicht:\s+\S+\s+von\s+(\S+)\s+Punkte\(n\)</div>.*
```

would match any line containing a string like:

```
<div class="box box-warning">Erreicht: X von Y Punkte(n)</div>
```

where `X` and `Y` are two words, the only varying parts are the number of spaces between the tokens and the `X` and `Y` words.

Comment: Hi! This approach seems to be very straight! I find all the relevant lines with ```LC_ALL="de_DE" awk -p 'x+=sub(/ von /,""){y+=$0}END{print x}' *.html``` (```x```) but the sum is allways zero. Because the following symbols are numeric and char/string? That means I have to cut off the `Punkte(n) ` ?

Answer (score 1):

> *Maybe there is even a more convenient solution...*

Yes there is. It has been repeated countless times on SO already; it's a really bad idea to parse HTML with `sed`, `awk` and the like. Please parse HTML with, you guessed it, an HTML parser! I can highly recommend [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel).

As you didn't share one of your HTML files, I'm going to assume the following example input:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="box box-warning">Erreicht: 0 von 3 Punkte(n)</div>
  <div class="box box-warning">Erreicht: 0 von 6 Punkte(n)</div>
  <div class="box box-warning">Erreicht: 0 von 9 Punkte(n)</div>
  <div class="box box-warning">Erreicht: 0 von 12 Punkte(n)</div>
  <div class="box box-warning">Erreicht: 0 von 15 Punkte(n)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$ xidel -s input.html -e '//div[@class="box box-warning"]'
Erreicht: 0 von 3 Punkte(n)
Erreicht: 0 von 6 Punkte(n)
Erreicht: 0 von 9 Punkte(n)
Erreicht: 0 von 12 Punkte(n)
Erreicht: 0 von 15 Punkte(n)

$ xidel -s input.html -e '//div[@class="box box-warning"] ! extract(.,"\d+",0,"*")[2]'
3
6
9
12
15

$ xidel -s input.html -e '
  sum(//div[@class="box box-warning"] ! integer(extract(.,"\d+",0,"*")[2]))
'
45
```